# SonarQube - boolean logic correctness -

Tags: java, sonarqube, boolean-expression

I have a problem with the logic expression on my method **matches1()**.

### Problem

SonarQube is telling me there is an error:
`(expectedGlobalRule == null && actual != null)`

> **SonarQube:**
>   Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to
>   "true".
>       Conditions should not unconditionally evaluate to "TRUE" or to "FALSE"

I'm essentially doing this logic to avoid a *NPE* on my "Block to be executed".

### My code

**matches1()**

```
private boolean matches1(GbRule actual, GbRule expected) {
     if(actual == null && expected == null) {
        return true;
     } else if((expected == null && actual != null) || (expected != null && actual == null)) {
        return false;
     } else {
       //Block to be executed
     }
}
```

I inverted the logic in to see what SonarQube would tell me and he doesn't complain about it.
**matches2()**

```
private boolean matches2(GbRule actual, GbRule expected) {
      if(actual == null && expected == null) {
         return true;
      } else if(expected != null && actual != null)  {
         //Block to be executed
      } else {
         return false;
      }
}
```

### Question

1. Do the problem is in my boolean logic or it's SonarQube that lost
   his mind?
2. If the problem is within sonarQube, how could I resolve it?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `expectedGlobalRule`?

Comment: Your parameter is named *expected*, but your code is using **expectedGlobalRule**. So typo - or on purpose? If the later - how is *expecectedGlobalRule*?

Comment: @garnulf expectedGlobalRule was not supposed to be there, I corrected it

Comment: Your are still getting the sonar issue now?

Comment: Yes, on my matcher1() there is still a SonarQube warning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in your logic. Let's take it piece by piece:

```
 if(actual == null && expected == null) {
    return true;
```

At this point if both vars are `null` then we're no longer in the method. So if we get any further, then at least one of them is non-null.

The viable options at this point are:

- actual = null, expected = non-null
- actual = non-null, expected = null
- actual = non-null, expected = non-null

Now, let's look at the next bit of code:

```
 } else if((expected == null && actual != null)
```

We already know that both variables can't be `null`, so as soon as we know `expected == null`, there's no need to test whether `actual != null`. That has already been proven by the fact that we got this far. So `actual != null` is always true, which is why an issue is raised.

**Edit**

This means that your code could be boiled down to:

```
private boolean matches1(GbRule actual, GbRule expected) {
  if(actual == null && expected == null) {
    return true;
  } else if(actual == null || expected == null) {
    return false;
  } 

  //Block to be executed
}
```

Note that the `else` isn't needed & dropping it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain me my mistake.

So if I understand well,  the problem here is that some of my expression are redundant(useless). 

The correct way to do it should be:
 `if((expectedRuleMap == null) || ( actual == null))`
Right?

Comment: IMO @GabrielAmyot the second version of the code is cleaner/clearer & is therefore the best one.

Comment: Ann
Ok, thank you.
I think the message raised by sonar is a little misleading.
What I understood about the message was that my **condition** would always be true so my **else** below would never be reached.

Comment: If we look at the **description** provided for squid:S2583:
`Conditional statements using a condition which cannot be anything but FALSE have the effect of **making blocks of code non-functional**. If the condition cannot evaluate to anything but TRUE, the **conditional statement is completely redundant**, and makes the code less readable.`

- So, according to this definition, I should either have **non-functional** code block or a **completely redundant** conditional statement. But this is not the case in my code(or is it?).

Comment: yes, in your original code ` && actual != null` is redundant

Comment: You are right.
Perhaps the problem here is my understanding of English.

But still, I think the message could be clearer.
I asked some people here at the office about this question and here in stack-overflow and nobody has figured it out.
I would recommend SonarQube to add more details in this particular description. I think the main interpretation issue is caused by the assumption that the whole conditional statement is redundant(what is not true).

Comment: @GabrielAmyot this is why we highlight only part of the line; to draw your attention to the part that needs fixing

Answer (score 3):

Even when the code is correct; seriously, it makes my eyes hurt. Thing is: it is **hard** to read. Such kind of nested conditions is something that one should not be writing in the first place.

If you can't avoid it; at least refactor it into something like

```
private boolean areActualAnedExpectedBothNull(args ...) {
  return actual == null && expectedGlobalRule == null;
}
```

And please note; you can dramatically simply your code:

```
if (areActualAnedExpectedBothNull(actual, expected)) {
  return true;
}
if (actual == null) {
  return false;
}

if (expected == null) {
  return false;
}

do your thing ...
```

and use such methods in your other code. And of course, you do a lot of unit testing; probably with coverage measurements; just to make sure that your tests really test **all** possible paths through this maze.

But as said; you better step back and think if there are ways to **avoid** writing such code in the first place.

The typical answer to booleans, and if/else chains in OO programming is **polymorphism**. So instead of asking something about its state; you turn to interfaces/abstract classes; and have different implementations of those. And then you have a factory giving you that implementation you need; and then you just call methods on that; without further need for if/else/whatever.

If you don't know what I am talking about - watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79); especially the second one!

Comment: Thank you for observation.
I'll definitely check out the videos

Comment: I'm gonna improve my code readability. Still, I would like to know why sonarQube is flagging my code as *wrong* when it's just *ugly*.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is with SonarQube.

See this article for more info on ignoring that issue: https://www.bsi-software.com/en/scout-blog/article/ignore-issues-on-multiple-criteria-in-sonarqube.html

You can just set it up to ignore that error within that file.

The gist of it is

> Open the Settings (SonarQube General Settings or project Settings) and
>   select the Exclusions category. Switch to the Issues Exclusions and
>   scroll down to “Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria”. Set squid:S00112
>   as Rule Key Pattern and **/*Activator.java as File Path Pattern.

You will need to change the rule key pattern to the pattern associated with the rule that is being violated for your code and the file pattern as the path of your .java file.

Comment: Why do you think the problem it with SonarQube?

I don't want to ignore that error.
I would prefer to correct the problem. Is it possible to modify the squid:S00112 to make it work well?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with SonarQube, at least in that matter. It's finding is perfectly valid, as you could sie with the other answers.

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer `if((expected == null && actual != null) || (expected != null && actual == null))` should be true when `expected = null` and `actual = null` but false when `expected != null && actual != null`. This case is not covered by the first condition.

Comment: @nhouser9 See [comment by G. Ann](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297636/sonarqube-boolean-logic-correctness/39297705#comment65934042_39298674) for clarification.